# How to parse JSON with two types of value, one as integer and another as JSON object?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, facebook-graph-api, resttemplate

When reading facebook graph api insights response it can have two types of response

```
   "data":{
      "name": "page_posts_impressions",
        "values": [
        {
          "value": 10,//integer value
          "end_time": "2019-07-29T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ]
     }
```

here inside values, value has integer value but in another case

```
 "data":{
      "name": "page_posts_impressions",
        "values": [
        {
          "value": { "post":10,
                      "tab":1
                    }//json object value

          "end_time": "2019-07-29T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ]
     }
```

here value has json object value, how can I parse these king of json object ?

Comment: So do you want to parse it using same PoJo?

Comment: yes @PratikAmbani

Comment: honestly i will say this is worst design, may be parsing it manually will be better choice @AmritMalla

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are going to parse this `JSON` to java POJO. Since `values` is `Array` of `Objects` i will suggest to parse that into `JsonNode`, which is

```
List<JsonNode> values;
```

Advantage's in this approach is `JsonNode` has couple of method to find whether it is `Integer` or `JsonObject`

[isInt()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#isInt())

```
public boolean isInt()
```

[isObject](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#isObject())

```
public final boolean isObject()
```